# number set with non-adjacent digits

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms

I'm not sure such thing exists, or even if I'm asking for a valid thing, but I'll do my best describing it. At least the thing I want is similar to Gray code, so should be valid.

So, I want to know name, generation algorithm, whatever you can help with about unordered set of numbers, of it will be better to say words, because leading zeros are accepted. Word length is fixed. And every two words are different by at least two digits, so by changing single digit in any word you can't get a word of the same set.

For instance, 12 and 34 form such set, because by changing any digit in 12, i.e. generating 1x and x2 numbers you'll never get 34. But, for sure this set is not full in term, more numbers of length 2 can be added (like 56) still keeping set properties.

So, I want any hint on how to generate/build/calculate whatever you call it full (largest?) set of words of given length N, such as any two words are different by at least two digits.

Comment: You're talking about a *code* (of length $N$, on an alphabet of size 10, with *minimal distance* 2). These are studied in *coding theory*. There are many open questions as to whether there are codes with this or that set of parameters.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the right terminology!